# Create watermark libreoffice writer 5.3.3.2

Tags: libreoffice

I'm currently using LibreOffice writer 5.3.3.2 running Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on a ASUS X550LA laptop, and want to insert a watermark reading "DRAFT" into, or behind the text in a text document. All help files and youtube I can find say:-
Format>page>background... and here it fails as I do not have a tab for background.

I do have:-
Organizer, Page,Area Transparency,Header, Footer, Borders,Columns, Footnote.

I'd really appreciate any help.

Hal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as I said in the original question:- All help files and youtube I can find say:- Format>page>background... and here it fails as I do not have a tab for background.

I do have:- Organizer, Page,Area Transparency,Header, Footer, Borders,Columns, Footnote. The page TAB gives COLOR as an option but there are NO graphic options.

Comment: Here's how you can add a transparent bookmark in LibreOffice Writer. (Tested in LibreOffice 6.x): [https://libreofficehelp.com/how-to-add-watermark-in-libreoffice-writer/](https://libreofficehelp.com/how-to-add-watermark-in-libreoffice-writer/)

Answer (score 1):

This short video should be helpful
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXdxK9JCW6Q

You need to have an image as a watermark (white image with "Draft" written in light gray on it, for example)

You can download some images  with Draft, Urgent, and so written in it,
here > http://www.apertura.co.nz/libreofficewatermarks

EDIT: I just upgraded to the Version: 5.4.x.x of LibreOffice, 
So now, You just need to go to > Format > Watermark, then a window open where you input the text you want for your watermark and choose the color of the watermark (which is a lot faster and easier)

Comment: Version 5.4 of LibreOfice is a development version and not recommended for production use: https://www.libreoffice.org/download/pre-releases/

Comment: @Graham I didn't know that, thanks for the info

Comment: Thank you Patrice, but as I said I do not see a Background Tab, but I appreciate your time in answering. You will see I accepted a solution from Arindam which worked for me.

Comment: I am now on LibreOffice 6.0.6 (stable for enterprise) U-M 16.04 like you, to add a watermark i do >Format>Watermark... (the 13th option in the Format menu).
Are you still on the LO 5.3.3?